# RDP connection to Debian 10 EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, rdp, debian-buster

I have tried multiple option available to connect my Debian EC2 instance through windows RDP, but none of them worked.
Please suggest some effective way to connect through RDP.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question, so most likely https://SuperUser.com is a better place for this question.

Comment: Also, if you say you've tried multiple ways and they didn't work... maybe you should list those ways and what went wrong?

Comment: Issue resolved. Security group was not configured properly for RDP port.